# TFS - Compare branch and export

Tags: sql-server, tfs

We currently use TFS 2010 for our VS applications and our SQL code. For SQL we have every stored procedure stored in different text files e.g."spname.sql" and we alter these files and then apply them to the Dev server.

When it comes to testing we then do a branchcompare to compare the DEV branch to the UAT branch to get a list of the .sql files that are different.

Question is, is there a way to export out the files in the list from the dev branch so we can them apply all the SQL code that has changed to the UAT server?

(We do table alters / updates etc in a "rollout" type script).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you do a compare in Visual Studio (with SSDT), you can choose to create a script instead of deploying. Or you could use powershell Get-TfsItemHistory with -Version to get the file list and then use that list to get the source.